# Check an associative array in other array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have two array `$A`,`$B`

```
$B = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_participant] => 94
            [full_name] => soeng makara
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_participant] => 95
            [full_name] => sok sao
        )

)

$A = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_participant] => 95
            [full_name] => sok sao
        )
)
```

Anyone could help me How can I check array `$A` in array `$B` in that case.

Comment: Is array $A always one element? If so, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply:

```
if (in_array($A[0], $B))
{
  // in array
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to know if the item in $a is in $b?

```
function checkIfInArray($a, $b)    
{
    foreach($b as $i)
        foreach($a as $x)
            if($x['id_participant'] == $i['id_participant']) return true; //Match found
    return false; //No Match was found
}
```

Comment: Mathews way is way better. :D